# Re-run code from certain point onwards in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am running quite a time consuming python code in PyCharm, where data is initially loaded, then a model is created etc.

I would like to know if it is possible to set a breakpoint at a particular point in the code where the state of the environment will be saved. From there on I want to make edits to the rest of the code, however ideally re-run from the breakpoint I set.

By doing this I would avoid the loading of data, and model training which would be a repeated process.

Is this possible in Python or is there such a functionality in PyCharm?
Thanks

Comment: One way doing it is through data serialisation - deserialisation. You execute the "stable" part once and serialize it. Then you run another script deserializing it and executing the "unstable" part. This can save you time (and I would recommand `pickle` for the serialisation library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK and according to [this question form 2014](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205816159-Is-it-possible-to-develop-code-in-debug-mode-), PyCharm does not support hot-swapping code during debug mode. When you set a breakpoint and do some changes in code they will not be applied.

You can however setup a Python propmt in debug console, which will have access to all your variables at the time of current code execution. You can modify their values and check why your code is failing. To do so just click on this icon

[image]

Comment: The question is not on hot-swapping code, but on restarting code at a given point. What you're describing here is just the standard debug procedure. They would still have to run their code up to a given point to get there, and would therefore not save any time.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do check the python code at breakpoints using pycharm debugger

Refer this for how to use it .[how to use a debugger in pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html)

You cannot use code modified code in between and then start from that breakpoints using debugger.

little hack to do this, one need to run the python code in debugger mode ie `python -i main.py` and also need to make sure that there in no interdependence of previous code to the new modified one.

Answer (score -1):

One option I have found is to convert your code to ipython notebook. Put all the heavy-weight/one-time run code in the first few cells and unstable/to be debugged code in the later cells.

Now, you run the first few cells one time, so the output from these cells is stored and readily available always for later cells. Whenever you change code in later cells, you only have to run those cells (unless you modified something in the earlier cells in which case you need to rerun those cells as well).

Pycharm/most python IDEs support running and debugging ipython notebook cells (individually or in groups).